# Adding To Calendar Date ... Not accurate?

Tags: java, android

Can anyone please help.
I am geting current date from Calendar.
I then would like to set a string to a new date by adding number of months..
When i use the following code it works when i add 12 months to date,
But when i try to add 1 month, then next date is January (+2 Months)
When i try to add 3 months, next date is April.
6 months, next date is October 2013 etc....
When trying to add 24, 36 or 48 Months it almost works but is 1 month early.
There doesn't seem to be a pattern to how the date is changing

```
//Get Current date and set as text
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, Retest);        // Months to Date
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);  
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if (month<=9)  { MONTH$ = "0"+month   ;}
    else {MONTH$ = ""+month;               }    //Set month to MM

   NextTest$ = ""+day+"/"+MONTH$+"/"+year;    //Put date ints into string DD/MM/YYYY

   Toast.makeText(this, "Re-Test Due.. "+NextTest$, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Please give a sample date, and bear in mind that you can definitely lose information by repeatedly adding months - what should January 30th + 1 month be?

Comment: You don't need to do all that, just use a `DateFormat` with "dd/MM/yyyy" pattern.

Comment: When I run your code with `Retest=1`, I get December 6th, 2013 (`6/11/2012` with 0-based month). `Retest=2`, I get January 6th, 2013. `Retest=3`, I get February 6th, 2013. As Jon said, you need to provide us with some sample input and output and possibly show how `Retest` is defined.

Comment: The code you provided does not display the behaviour you describe in JDK6. edit: What he said ^

Comment: Isntead of `Calendar` class, why dont you use `joda-time` that provides more real realization of earth date and time. And agree with Mr. @JonSkeet, about loss of information. Also think about the question he asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Java Docs , If any value is passed to Calender's Add Function, is larger than the Field's value than it will add the modulo of it . Refer [GregorianCalender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) docs

Answer (score 2):

In Calender API January is mapped to 0, so month October is mapped to 9. So if you are trying to find out the current month as per the human calender, so add 1 to java calender's month value, then only calculate the value.

```
int day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; //It should work for you.  
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: @Coops5575 Did my solution work for you? Or were you looking for something else?